# SQL Syntax Error(missing operator) Microsoft Access in Case Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, case

I am working on a SQL query but cannot get started in the following case statement because I keep running into this error. The current query looks like this:

```
SELECT CoupaData.PO, CoupaData.Line, CoupaData.[Work Order #], CoupaData.Item, CoupaData.LineTotal,
       CoupaData.Received, CoupaData.ApprovedInvoiced, CoupaData.[Line Status], 
       (CASE 
          WHEN CoupaData.LineTotal = CoupaData.Received THEN 'YES'
          ELSE 'NO'
        END) AS gg
FROM CoupaData;
```

Comment: Does Access even support a `case` expression? Try `iif` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Case statements aren't allowed in JET SQL.  Try the inline if statement. You can nest these as well if you have multiple conditions.

```
    SELECT 
     CoupaData.PO
    , CoupaData.Line
    , CoupaData.[Work Order #]
    , CoupaData.Item
    , CoupaData.LineTotal
    , CoupaData.Received
    , CoupaData.ApprovedInvoiced
    , CoupaData.[Line Status]
    , IIf(CoupaData.LineTotal = CoupaData.Received, 'YES', 'NO') AS gg
    FROM CoupaData;
```